# How to add initialization to a windows batch loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file with a loop that I want to run at a regular interval. At the start of each day - right after midnight when the day changes - I want to run an extra bit of batch commands just once. This is what I came up with so far:

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set dow=%%i
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
)
set previousDate=%month%_%day%_%year%

:loop
timeout /t 5 /nobreak

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set dow=%%i
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
)
set currentDate=%month%_%day%_%year%

if not previousDate==currentDate 
(
        echo ONLY DO THIS ONCE A DAY        
        previousDate=currentDate
)
echo DO THIS EVERY LOOP INTERVAL
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
goto :loop
```

I'll be honest I'm a total newbie at batch files. What I am expecting with the above is to see the console window print out - only once per day - "ONLY DO THIS ONCE A DAY" followed by "DO THIS EVERY LOOP INTERVAL" printed out every 5 seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

What I actually see is the image below.

[image]

Comment: If that's a direct copy/paste, you need to use `if not %previousDate%==%currentDate% (` (note the open parentheses on the same line as the `if` and the percents around the variables).

Comment: Read the help text appearing when typing `if /?` into a command prompt window; you will find that yout `if` syntax is wrong, you need to place the opening `(` of the conditional block on the same line as the `if` command itself and the comparison expression, separated by a space...#

Comment: I would recommend to use the windows Task Scheduler, its very simple...

Comment: I cannot setup Task Scheduler on every computer that my client is running. But I can email a *.bat file and tell them to "click it".

Comment: Thank you for the open parentheses observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified version of what you appear to be doing:

```bat
@echo off

:loop
call :sub one
echo DO THIS EVERY LOOP INTERVAL
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
call :sub two
if not %two%==%one% (
    echo ONLY DO THIS ONCE A DAY        
)
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
goto :loop

:sub
set "%1="
for /f %%i in ("%date%") do if not defined %1 set "%1=%%i"
```

All I'm doing is setting the variables %one% and %two% as either Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, or Sun, *based on your date format*, as soon as those are not equal there must have been a day change.

Comment: This seems like it might work except that to test it I'd have to wait until midnight. Is there a way to make it ONLY DO THIS ONCE A DAY as the first thing it does, than enter the loop - as I'm attempting to do in my example? Your example is sophisticated - I'll need to research what you are doing to understand it.

Comment: So simple: I simply placed echo ONLY DO THIS ONCE A DAY just before :loop. Thank you!